# Refactoring method that was previously injected with implement

Tags: javascript, mootools

Greetings, 
   I'm trying to override or extend the Element.show() and .hide() methods in mootools in order to add some WAI-Aria toggling. I was trying to use the Class.Refactor() method like this:

```
 Element = Class.refactor(Element, {

 show: function(displayString) {
   result = this.previous(displayString);
   // Do my thing
   return result;
 },

 hide: function() {
   result = this.previous();
   // Do my thing
   return result;
 }

});
```

however, this is not working, previous is null and I think the reason is that Mootools injects those methods through Element.implement. So the methods are not native?

I have figured out how to completely replace .show and .hide but I would like to retain all of their existing functionality and just add to it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not a refactor guy myself, but you can always do it 'old school' and save the previous function in a variable (`_prev_show` and `_prev_hide` for example), then do your override and call those functions from your new methods.

second option would be to try extending Element into itself and call `this.parent()`, this is the 'unsafe' version of Class.Refactor. [[reference]](http://www.clientcide.com/wiki/cnet-libraries/01.1-class.extras/00-class.refactor)

Comment: also posted a full example from a coworker which does exactly as you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from a coworker. He's not on SO so I'm posting on his behalf and will buy him a beer the next time we are in the same city:

Class.refactor doesn't work on Natives (Element, Array, String, etc.)
because they aren't Classes nor can they be overrided to be; MooTools just
adds some cool prototypes to make them more Class-like and fun and easy to
work with.

The way to extend natives is to use the implement() method; The only problem
is that this.parent() and this.previous() don't exist, so you have to get a
bit trickier to extend existing methods without rewriting them:

---

```
(function(){ // Keeps the window namespace clean

   var old_hide = Element.prototype.hide;
   var old_show = Element.prototype.show;

   Element.implement({
       hide: function() {
           result = old_hide.run(arguments, this); // Calls old method
           alert("Hiding " + this.get('tag') );
           return result;
       },
       show: function(display) {
           result = old_show.run(arguments, this); // Calls old method
           alert("Showing " + this.get('tag') );
           return result;
       }
   });

})(); // Closes the private function and executes it immediately
```

---

The key concepts here are:

1 - Encapsulate the whole shebang in a private, self-executing function so
the global namespace isn't polluted by our variable assignments for the
original methods (e.g. old_hide and old_show);

2 - Use the Native object's implement() method to override each function,
much like you had done as the second argument to Class.refactor;

3 - Instead of calling this.parent() or this.previous() in each method, you
call the old prototypes using MooTools' run() method, which passes the
arguments with a binding to the function and executes it.

As before, make sure to gather the result of the function.run() call and
return it to maintain API consistency.

Answer (score 0):

About the last comment by ryber, I'm confused because I made up an example is jsFiddle refactoring the Element class ([Sample](http://www.jsfiddle.net/KdNsM/12/)). 
The trick is that, when I tried to use that example in a real application it didn't work and I ended up here looking for a reason.